# Setting WPF Window Background to Resource Dictionary Brush User Setting

Tags: wpf, xaml, application-settings

I have two brushes declared in my ResourceDictionary and I would like the user to select which background they want to see on the main window.

Resource Dictionary Brushes:
`x:Key="LightBlueMainWindow"`
`x:Key="DarkBlueMainWindow"`

Window:
`Background="{DynamicResource LightBlueMainWindow}">`

I have a project User Setting defined 'MainBackground' which is a string and can contain either key (LightBlueMainWindow or DarkBlueMainWindow).

What is the best way to dynamically set the background based on the user setting in XAML?

**EDIT**

I need to mention that I need to access this brush from many different user controls and windows throughout the application.  I don't want to set a property on every single place I want to set this brush.

Also, the brushes are pre-defined and not just a color like this

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBlueMainWindow" EndPoint="0.5,1" 
                     MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>            
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE9EFF3" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF84A1B8" Offset="1"/>
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood your question, do you want to specify this only once and then it should be set for all Windows and UserControls in the application? I understood it like you wanted to be able to specify the MainBackground string as the resource-key for the background..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will require a couple of steps

You'll need a converter since you can't bind x:Key of a StaticResource or DynamicResource. For the converter to be able to get easy access to the resources they should be added at appliaction level

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="BrushesDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:ApplicationResourceKeyConverter x:Key="ApplicationResourceKeyConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**ApplicationResourceKeyConverter**

```
public class ApplicationResourceKeyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string key = value as string;
        return Application.Current.TryFindResource(key);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you can bind the MainWindow Background property to the user settings string MainBackground like

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:ProjectProperties="clr-namespace:YourProjectName.Properties" 
        Background="{Binding Source={x:Static ProjectProperties:Settings.Default},
                             Path=MainBackground,
                             Converter={StaticResource ApplicationResourceKeyConverter}}">
    <!--...-->
</Window>
```

Comment: This looks like the exact solution I'm looking for.  Unfortunately I cannot get the correct reference to the project properties in the xaml.  WpfApplication1.Properties is not included in the assembly.  I've tried WpfApplication1.MySettings as well with no luck.  I'm so close.

Comment: Another note: My project does not have a root namespace. My app.config contains this:    <MySettings>
      <setting name="MainBackground" serializeAs="String">
        <value>GasMainMainWindow</value>
      </setting>
    </MySettings>

Comment: Just found out you can't reference user settings from xaml in a vb.net WPF application if your root namespace is blank.  Now to fix my 100 reference errors for adding the namespace...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using DynamicResource, just have the user pick and set the background, or have a property called UserChosenColor and bind the Background to that.

You could also bind to the property in your settings (MainBackground) by using a converter that converted a string to a Brush.

**Edit**

Since the user changed his question as a method of setting every window to a chosen background, it's also simple.  Define a style with a setter like this:

```
<!-- Window style -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MainBackground, Mode=OneWay, Converter=StringToBrushConverter}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Both your ideas could work but might not in my specific situation.  I've edited my question.

Comment: After re-reading the question I think this is more what the OP wanted.. Although to get it to work you'll need to add a Style for every Window and UserControl in the application since the Style for Window will only apply to Window and not the Windows that derives from Window, like MainWindow etc. You'll also need to convert the resource-key to an actual resource if the string value shall be stored in the user settings